# ¿"Whistleblower" en castellano sin que sea peyorativo?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término

En el periodismo se usa con frecuencia el término inglés *whistleblower*. Por ejemplo en [este artículo](http://www.eldiario.es/escolar/filtrador-Papeles-Castellana-medalla-carcel_6_620897946.html) leo:

> Gracias a este ‘**whistleblower**’ –sea quien sea–, pudimos conocer la lista de la amnistía fiscal revelada por Los Papeles de la Castellana: cuánto dinero tenían sin declarar y qué exiguo porcentaje pagaron gracias al Gobierno de Rajoy cuando lo legalizaron.

Está hablando de una persona (en principio desconocida) que consiguió unos papeles sobre unos movimientos fiscales para pagar menos impuestos.

Se trata de alguien que informa de algo a alguien que puede dar voz al asunto, especialmente la prensa. Según la acepción que veo y entiendo, esa persona tiende a hacerlo desde el anonimato para protegerse de las consecuencias penales, pero también eligiendo bien a quién se lo pasa para que esa información afecte lo más posible.

Tan grande es el movimiento actual que hay plataformas seguras para garantizar la seguridad de quien informa, y [así lo explica el mismo periódico](http://www.eldiario.es/redaccion/eldiarioes-colaborador-herramienta-filtraciones-Filtrala_6_252034807.html):

> Filtrala.org es un proyecto de la [Associated Whistle-Blowing Press](https://awp.is/es/), es una organización sin ánimo de lucro con sede en Bélgica - que tiene uno de los marcos legales que más protegen a las fuentes de información - y dedicada a promocionar la transparencia de los asuntos públicos a través de las filtraciones anónimas. (...)
>
> El fenómeno de lo que en inglés se conoce como *whistleblowing* (que se puede traducir como chivatazo, pero sin connotaciones negativas) se ha multiplicado gracias a la democratización de las herramientas que permiten un uso de Internet confidencial y más seguro.

Observamos, pues, que el propio redactor de la noticia se dio cuenta del problema de encontrar una palabra en castellano (y no encontró este sitio para plantearla). *Chivatazo*, o el adjetivo *chivato*, tienen parte de su significado, pero tienen una connotación negativa que no se considera apropiada para este caso. *Delator* podría también servir, pero incurre en el mismo problema.

Es por eso que me surge la duda de si tenemos en el castellano alguna palabra para traducir *whistleblower* que no tenga connotación negativa, o incluso la tenga positiva.

Comment: En Chile usamos un verbo que es positivo: _datear_. Pero no usamos _datero_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alertador) traduce el término como **alertador**

> Un **alertador** —término cuyo uso no está extendido— también llamado **lanzador de alerta** o **revelador de secretos**, define a [...]

En el artículo también se explica:

> Cabe destacar que en muchos países se usa el término **soplón**, el cual es muy frecuente en una conversación cotidiana y puede tener connotaciones negativas, al contrario que el término whistleblower en inglés. Es posible encontrar que en países como Venezuela, Colombia y Costa Rica, se usa el término **sapo**, el cual es coloquial.

Aunque no se indica si `sapo`, además de coloquial, tiene también connotaciones negativas.

Answer (score 9):

Tienes dos: ***[informador](http://dle.rae.es/?id=LXtJrse)*** e ***[informante](http://dle.rae.es/?id=LXyw5y0)***, ambas con el significado de "que informa". La he visto usar mucho en películas: mi hijo mayor está ahora enganchado a ver *Cars* y *Cars 2*, y en esta segunda en una escena un personaje comenta que tiene un informador que es quien le da los chivatazos y le cuenta lo que se cuece en determinado negocio.

Otros ejemplos en prensa (negritas mías):

> *Los expertos antiterroristas sostienen desde hace tiempo que dentro del colectivo de estudiantes, la organización terrorista tiene una importante red de **informadores**, que son los que le han facilitado los datos al "comando Madrid" para acabar con la vida de Francisco Tomás y Valiente.*
>
> El Mundo, 15/02/1996.
>
> ---
>
> *Frente a los últimos hechos de orden público registrados en Antioquia, el Gobernador dijo que dispondrá de $400 millones anuales para conformar una red de **informantes** que advertirán sobre posibles acciones de la guerrilla contra la población civil en la troncal occidental y la Autopista Medellín-Bogotá.*
>
> El País, 08/07/1997.

Comment: Me gusta... y además me vas introduciendo títulos de cine infantil que acabaré viendo :) Lo que me cuesta un poco es ver cómo el _informante_ puede llevar implícito que es alguien que quiere preservar el anonimato, algo que _whistleblower_ lleva bastante asociado. Por el contexto ambas noticias llevan asociado ese matiz, eso sí. También es curioso ver que coexistan dos palabras tan parecidas etimológicamente y con el mismo significado.

Comment: En el cine policíaco, al menos en España, se oye mucho el término "confidente", que según la RAE es "Persona que sirve de espía y trae noticias de lo que pasa en el campo enemigo o entre gentes sospechosas"

Comment: @JorgeUrreta buena opción, puedes plantearla como respuesta, y así fedorqui tendrá más donde elegir. :-)

Comment: El único problema con informador/informante es que estas pueden implicar el informar a lo largo de un determinado tiempo, mientras whistleblower, como debe implicar, (pero quizás no tan obviamente) es más bien el que avisa por primera vez pero de ahí deja que otros hagan la investigación. Pero bueno, puede que no haga falta tal distinción, siendo necesario solo un adjetivo como «informador inicial» o «informante avisador» o parecido

Comment: Lo que si es extraño es que @fedorqui no haya visto Cars ni Cars 2. _Póngase las pilas_ que ya sale la 3

Comment: @DGaleano jajaja estoy gozando del poco tiempo que me queda antes de empezar a ver películas que no me apetezca ver :D Aunque visto el caso de Carlos, ¡son una mina para interrogarse sobre la lengua!

Comment: Un whistleblower no necesariamente revela la información una sola vez. Podría hacerlo en repetidas ocasiones, el término es simplemente peyorativo porque ¿a quién le gusta que lo *agarren como el tigre de Santa Julia* ?. Oh ¡eso podría ser una buena pregunta!

Answer (score 4):

Yo iba a decir:

> activista

Pero luego Linguee me dió:

> **denunciante** (Google lo define como "persona que interpone una denuncia".)

Lo cual me parece mejor... y muchísimo mejor que "informador", "informante" y "soplón".

"Fuente" no funciona, porque el *whistleblower* toma la iniciativa, y la fuente no necesariamente.

Una vez oí una charla dada por Roger Boisjoly, el que trató de impedir el desastre del Challenger (es la triste [historia de los *O-rings* defectuosos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accidente_del_transbordador_espacial_Challenger#Preocupaci%C3%B3n_por_las_juntas_t%C3%B3ricas)).  Si uno de veras quiere entender el papel retador del *whistleblower*, esa historia es impresionante.

¿Pero entonces por qué no usé "denunciante" en esa frase?  Es que *whistleblower* tiene aún connotaciones que no capto bien bien de "denunciante".  Pero "denunciante" se acerca más que cualquier otra palabra que se me ocurre.

Comment: Esta me gusta. Denunciante para mi tiene una connotación altruista. Se denuncia con el fin de alertar sobre algo. El soplón denuncia casi siempre para perjudicar a alguien. Al informante le pagan u obtiene algún beneficio por contar. _Whistleblower_ se me parece más a denunciante porque soplón, informante e informador se parecen más a _snitch_ o a _mole_

Answer (score 3):

Los periodistas usan **fuente** para referirse a un informante relativamente confidencial.

Según el diccionario, *fuente* significa "persona o cosa que proporciona información" así que en rigor no nos sirve mucho como respuesta. Pero, al igual que *informador*, cuando se despersonaliza al que entrega la información y se le asigna un denominador general y abstracto, se le está dando una cierta "atmósfera" de secreto. Nótese la deferencia entre estas dos frases:

> El diputado sabía de las cuentas bancarias, según indicó una fuente.
>
> El diputado sabía de las cuentas bancarias, según indicó el Comisario Pérez.

Answer (score 2):

Informador e informante son perfectas, pero también tenemos **soplón**

Esta última tiene la connotación de la que habla fedorqui de que *informa una sola vez, queriendo quedarse en el anonimato*.

> [Soplón](http://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=YOpzdwI):  1. adj. coloq. Dicho de una persona: Que acusa en secreto y cautelosamente. U. t. c. s.

Aunque la connotación de soplón no es del todo positiva, no es tan negativa como la de chivato, sapo, campanero, delator, entre otras.

Comment: Esta debe ser la traducción más cercana, que todos los asépticos, políticamente correctos y técnicos terminos ofrecidos en las demás respuestas. En México, usamos también "**farol**" como una alegoría a la lámpara da luz revelando lo que ocurre bajo la protección de la obscuridad. Ambos términos son peyorativos y connitativos de traición. **Chismoso** se acerca pero connota provecho subrepticio para quien revela la información haciéndolo más despreciable que el soplón o farol, quienes no ganan nada al traicionar la confianza, o revelar la información sin intención de traición.