# ¿Hay alguna expresión en español para la frase en inglés "blow the whistle"?

Tags: solicitud-de-modismo

En inglés "blow the whistle" significa "llamar la atención sobre algo a otras personas para evitar que algo malo suceda". ¿Hay alguna expresión para esta frase en español?

Comment: Fundéu sugiere que *whistleblower* debería ser traducido como *[filtrador](http://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/filtrador-no-implica-ser-topo/)*, pero esto no es de gran ayuda porque *blow the whistle* es algo más amplio que "filtrar información" (*à la* Snowden).

Comment: La pregunta sobre *whistleblower* trata del sustantivo y de cómo no traducirlo peyorativamente, mientras que ésta trata de la expresión verbal. Esperaría a ver qué le parece al OP.

Comment: Opino lo mismo que dijo el otro Pablo. Igual la otra pregunta se relaciona de algun modo, podrian dejarle el link en comentarios  como "relacionado"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [¿"Whistleblower" en castellano sin que sea peyorativo?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/21122/whistleblower-en-castellano-sin-que-sea-peyorativo)

Comment: En inglés he oído frecuentemente *whistleblower* pero no *blow the whistle*.  Acepto tu definición pero creo que también un whistleblower puede sonar una alerta depués de que algo malo sucedió.

Comment: No creo que sea necesario que ponga el link del video en donde escuché la expresion, o si?

Comment: @aparente001 : De hecho la alerta la suelen dar de algo malo que ha ocurrido / se ha hecho pero que no es conocido (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whistleblower), para alertar y que se corrija. Creo que en EE.UU. a veces hay un componente económico adicional: si como consecuencia de la alerta, la empresa es multada, el whistleblower se lleva un %.

Comment: @aparente001: en el mismo artículo de Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whistleblower) aparece muchas veces  *blow the whistle* como lo que hace el *whistleblower*. Por ejemplo: "A person is diligently tasked with the conundrum of choosing to be loyal to the company or **to blow the whistle** on the company's wrongdoing."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En España se puede utilizar la expresión "Tirar de la manta" o "Descubrir el pastel"

Más acerca de esta expresión se puede leer [aquí](http://www.fraseshechas.net/tirar-de-la-manta/)

Answer (score -2):

En México se dice "soplar"  y a los que lo hacen se les dice "soplones".

Tambien puede ser usado "chismoso" o "metiche"

http://dle.rae.es/?id=YOpzdwI

> 1. adj. coloq. Dicho de una persona: Que acusa en secreto y cautelosamente. U. t. c. s.

También existe un coloquialismo en México llamado "ehar aguas", que es para ayudar prevenir a alguien de que las cosas no salgan mal.

> voy a mover el mueble, echame aguas
>
> > por lo común para pedir ayuda de que le avise si algo se puede caer
>
> voy a brincarme la barda, echame aguas
>
> > para avisar de que no hay nadie a la deriva

Comment: *Whistleblowing* no tiene que que ser ni secreto ni cauteloso.  Creo que el origen del termino es aplicar el freno de emergencia en un tren.  Eso es un acto bastante dramatico y obvio (para dar un ejemplo).  // *Soplón* me parece que tiene un tono más peyorativo que *whistleblower*.  Echa un ojo a https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/21122/9385

Comment: en eso tienes razon, soplon termina siendo un peyorativo,  
lo que hace que me venga a la mente una frace que tambien tenemos en México: "echarle aguas" que es cuando alguien esta cuidando que algo malo no pase. (la explicare en mi respuesta)

Comment: Con "metechie" quieres decir *metiche*?  Roger Boisjoly estaba realizando su trabajo, muy correctamente, de NASA cuando sonó la alerta de los O-rings del Challenger.

Comment: Problemas de autocorrector....